# Unwanted character at the end of printf

Tags: c++, string, printf

I have written a small program that takes a string input, and outputs the string with each character number moved up by 3. Only problem is at the end of each string it prints a `%` character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Input message: " << std::endl;
    std::string mes;
    std::cin >> mes;
    for(char& c : mes)
    {
        printf ("%c", c+3);
    }
}
```

This is the use and output of the program:

```
Input message:
hi
kl%
```

Comment: std::cout and printf in the same program? ok, why not

Comment: @krzaq nice find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are seeing is the prompt from your shell after your program ends, since you're not printing a newline.

Throw in a `printf("\n");` right before your `main` exits and you will get the result you want.

Demo of working code by adding newline: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ojJ7mozen4TA4qke